# Google pubsub client for swift using swift grpc client?

Tags: swift, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

Anybody aware of a client or example code to talk to google pubsub service from swift on the server (aka can't use the objective-c implementation)?

I'm assuming that using grpc would be the recommended way -- wondering if anyone has implemented this before and shared code for it?